# Wordpress Creating Theme - Linking Bootstrap stylesheets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am learning to create Wordpress theme and stuck at the very beginning where you link your stylesheets in a way Wordpress is designed to run.

I am using this template tag `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>` as in 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">` to let Wordpress read the default style.css but the problem I am having is to do
with loading stylesheets other than this.

To link extra css, I use this template tag `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`
as in `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
but it doesn't seem to load the style properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to get a copy of this: http://www.rootstheme.com/ and modify to create your own theme.

Comment: Thanks. This theme looks quite promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `bloginfo('template_directory')`? does it give the right path?

You could insert additional link tags to include your stylsheets, like:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

An other solution could be to use: @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); in your main css file.

So use in your template `<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">` this wil include style.css:

style.css:

```
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); 
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'); 
 body { 
 padding-top: 60px; 
 padding-bottom: 40px; 
 }
```

Which part don't work? Have you include the bootstrap-responsive.css too? Have you include the bootstrap javascript files?

See this link: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial for more example code.

Comment: Using this tag `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` as you suggested worked for me. Thanks a lot.